# How to do canary deployments?

Tags: amazon-web-services, canary-deployment

I have an AWS environment with one ALB, two api nodes and an RDS. I perform in place deployments today. I read about [canary releases](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CanaryRelease.html) and was wondering how I could transform my current environment to use canary deployments. My environment is entirely on AWS. The main question I have is about routing, what service/component is needed to dial up/down?

Answer (score 1):

Route53's [Weighted Routing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-weighted), The big disadvantage of this approach is that propagating DNS changes can take some time, another approach is to use autoscaling groups(ASG) to upscale the new version and then downscale the old version once you are confident.

> Weighted routing lets you associate multiple resources with a single
>   domain name (example.com) or subdomain name (acme.example.com) and
>   choose how much traffic is routed to each resource. This can be useful
>   for a variety of purposes, including load balancing and testing new
>   versions of software.